# How to initialize a UIView as header of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I'm new to iOS programming and i tried to follow the example of building an UITableViewController in the book of BIG NERD RANCH IOS PROGRAMMING 4TH EDITION but with a storyboard instead of nibs.

everything works except that the UIView i added for the header does not appear.

i added UIView to the UIViewTableController on top of the Prototype Cells in the storyboard. In the UIView, i had two buttons. Setting the UITableViewController as initial view controller, the storyboard appears as i designed in the storyboard. But when i use AppDelegate.m, adding lines of

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    TableTest *table = [[TableTest alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = table;
    return YES;
}
```

The UIView doesn't appear. I have assigned outlet for the UIView as headerView and tried

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UIView *header = self.headerView;
    return header;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 40;

}
```

It shows a blank gray header so i suppose the UIView is not initialized...

So I tried with my limited knowledge and a little search on the Internet by adding

```
(UIView *) headerView{
    if(!_headerView){
          _headerView = [_headerView init]
    }
    return _headerView
 }
```

still not working

How should I initialize it so it would appear when I use the AppDelegate?

Comment: what is _headerView = [_headerView init] . try  _headerView = [UIView new];

Comment: the question should be tableview section header and not tableview header

Answer (score 0):

put this code in viewdidload method

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = ({
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 183.0f)];
        view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.376 green:0.086 blue:0.09 alpha:1];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 0, 24)];
        label.text = @"ffff";
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:21];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [label sizeToFit];
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;


        [view addSubview:label];
        view;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I forgot to initialize the storyboard. well it's kinda stupid.
I assigned the storyboard ID and rewrote the init method by

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
return [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableTest"];
```

it works